# I cannot create a plot in Python, Python is crashing with datetime arrays

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

b = [datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 10, 17, 22, 91000), datetime.datetime(1900,   
     1,1,10,17,22, 153000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 10, 17, 22, 746000),   
     datetime.datetime(1900, 1,    1, 10, 17, 23, 89000)]

a = range(len(b))

plt.plot(b,a)
plt.show()
```

On Executing this Code Python is crashing, Anybody knows why?

Comment: Since i can't reproduce (p2.7), Post your trace-back it will be much easier.

Comment: @Kobi K: No Traceback exists, since it is not throwing an error, it is crashing the python.

Comment: How do you run your python code? can you try from the cmd so you'll see that there is no trace-back as you say.

Comment: just did, no traceback, just another dialogue box saying "python.exe has stopped working"

Comment: With python 3.3.2 in my ubuntu your code it works good. Have you installed Matplotlib right, and your Python is O.K.?

Comment: Does it happen with other script? what is your python version? what is your os? does it happen just with matplotlib script?

Comment: my python works fine, it is Python 2.7, and i am using windows, infact when I am doing this with some other combination of datetimes it is working fine, i think there is some problem with matplotlib, not the way it is installed but the way i am using it